# One of two Status Reason items are missing from the dropdown inside a Form header

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, microsoft-dynamics

I have a custom entity with the following StateCode/StatusCode definition:

> State ACTIVE
>
> - Active (value: 1)
> - Completed (value: 821290000)
>
> State INACTIVE
>
> - Inactive (value: 2)

Inside a form, I put Status Reason option set in the header for users to change as needed (in short: once they are done with the record, they change status reason from `Active` to `Completed`).

In the production environment (SP1 UR3 - version 6.1.3) the status reason `Completed` is missing and we only see `Active`.

In one of the development environment ('vanilla' SP1 - version 6.1.0) the exact same form shows both `Active` and `Completed` status reasons as expected.

Status Reason field shows the options are both there in both environments.

The two environments are exactly the same customizations-wise, there isn't any code which removes options from the option set (I wrote all the code for that entity, and I also triple-checked to make sure I wasn't overlooking anything).

Is this a bug in UR3 ?

**UPDATE**: I'm told the issue was permissions-related, going to post an answer with the details once I recollect them.

Comment: Are you sure the "Completed" option is on the Status Reason field in the entity's customizations? It is probably not in the customizations on your production environment. Just because it's on the development environment doesn't mean the Solution was exported/imported correctly.

Comment: `Status Reason field shows the options are both there in both environments.`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't heard of any bug of this sort.

Did you check if the status reason field on this custom entity has all 3 of those options in the field schema, and they are just not showing on the form?  This would help determine if there is some kind of form scripting issue/display issue versus a schema issue (like what pkr asked)

If you were to export the default solution and compare the customizations.xml files, are there differences?  If there are truly no differences between the two customizations files (meaning the environments are completely identical in terms of CRM customizations), then there has to be some kind of scripting that is causing the other option to not display in one environment based on some data but is showing in the other because the data is different.

Comment: There were no scripting issues, it was something else... I don't have the details at hand (a colleague of mine found out the root cause) but I recall it being somehow a permissions misconfiguration.

Comment: Interesting, I wouldn't expect permissions to cause something like this.  If you are able to get your hands on the root cause/solution, can you update the question by answering your own question - I am curious to see what was going on, as others who experience this issue down the line may be as well.